# Xcode immediately crashes after opening a new project

Tags: xcode

```
$ 14:51:33 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
2020-04-05 14:51:44.095 Xcode[5709:184457] -[__NSCFNumber hasPrefix:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xed1bd6c1b1e0a897
2020-04-05 14:51:44.099 Xcode[5709:184457] [MT] DVTAssertions: UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSInvalidArgumentException): -[__NSCFNumber hasPrefix:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xed1bd6c1b1e0a897
UserInfo: (null)
Hints:
  0: Sending newProject: to IDEApplicationCommands from (null)
  1: Sending openNewProjectAssistant: to IDEWelcomeWindowController from <IDEWelcomeWindowHighlightButton: 0x7fbc46da41b0>
2020-04-05 14:51:44.116 Xcode[5709:184457] [MT] DVTAssertions:
Backtrace:
  0   __exceptionPreprocess (in CoreFoundation)
  1   DVTFailureHintExceptionPreprocessor (in DVTFoundation)
  2   objc_exception_throw (in libobjc.A.dylib)
  3   -[NSObject(NSObject) __retain_OA] (in CoreFoundation)
  4   ___forwarding___ (in CoreFoundation)
  5   _CF_forwarding_prep_0 (in CoreFoundation)
  6   __68-[IDEWorkspaceWindowController _purgeOldIdentifiersFromUserDefaults]_block_invoke_2 (in IDEKit)
  7   __68-[IDEWorkspaceWindowController _purgeOldIdentifiersFromUserDefaults]_block_invoke (in IDEKit)
  8   _dispatch_client_callout (in libdispatch.dylib)
  9   _dispatch_once_callout (in libdispatch.dylib)
 10   -[IDEWorkspaceWindowController _purgeOldIdentifiersFromUserDefaults] (in IDEKit)
 11   -[IDEWorkspaceWindowController windowDidLoad] (in IDEKit)
 12   -[NSWindowController _windowDidLoad] (in AppKit)
 13   -[NSWindowController window] (in AppKit)
 14   -[IDEDocumentController _openUntitledWorkspaceDocumentAndDisplay:simpleFilesFocused:forSingleFile:editorDocumentURLOrNil:error:] (in IDEKit)
 15   -[IDEApplicationCommands newTemplateForTemplateKind:template:] (in IDEKit)
 16   -[IDEApplicationCommands newProject:] (in IDEKit)
 17   -[NSApplication(NSResponder) sendAction:to:from:] (in AppKit)
 18   __37-[DVTApplication sendAction:to:from:]_block_invoke.86 (in DVTKit)
 19   DVTInvokeWithFailureHint (in DVTFoundation)
 20   -[DVTApplication sendAction:to:from:] (in DVTKit)
 21   +[IDECommandManager sendActionForCommandWithIdentifier:from:] (in IDEKit)
 22   -[NSApplication(NSResponder) sendAction:to:from:] (in AppKit)
 23   __37-[DVTApplication sendAction:to:from:]_block_invoke.86 (in DVTKit)
 24   DVTInvokeWithFailureHint (in DVTFoundation)
 25   -[DVTApplication sendAction:to:from:] (in DVTKit)
 26   -[NSControl sendAction:to:] (in AppKit)
 27   __26-[NSCell _sendActionFrom:]_block_invoke (in AppKit)
 28   -[NSCell _sendActionFrom:] (in AppKit)
 29   -[NSButtonCell _sendActionFrom:] (in AppKit)
 30   NSControlTrackMouse (in AppKit)
 31   -[NSCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] (in AppKit)
 32   -[NSButtonCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] (in AppKit)
 33   -[NSControl mouseDown:] (in AppKit)
 34   -[NSWindow(NSEventRouting) _handleMouseDownEvent:isDelayedEvent:] (in AppKit)
 35   -[NSWindow(NSEventRouting) _reallySendEvent:isDelayedEvent:] (in AppKit)
 36   -[NSWindow(NSEventRouting) sendEvent:] (in AppKit)
 37   -[NSApplication(NSEvent) sendEvent:] (in AppKit)
 38   -[IDEApplication sendEvent:] (in IDEKit)
 39   -[NSApplication run] (in AppKit)
 40   NSApplicationMain (in AppKit)
 41   main (in Xcode)
 42   start (in libdyld.dylib)
Abort trap: 6
```

This is my first time installing XCode on my MacbookPro

I'm on macOS Catalin Version 10.15.4

### What I tried

- Installing different versions of Xcode: 11.4, 11.3, 10.1
- `sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools && xcode-select --install`
- `sudo xcodebuild -license`
- Removing ~/Library/Caches
- Removing /Library/Caches
- Removing ~/Library/Developer
- `defaults delete com.apple.dt.xcode`

Comment: You say "a new project". Do you mean a completely plain vanilla project created from the ios / mac os application template? Or is there something in it that you've put there?

Comment: Also: what kind of MacBook Pro do you have? Does it have any custom utilities installed that might be causing this? It looks like a problem when you click a button; so this is not actually on launch, you are _doing_ something: what are you doing? what button is it? Does the problem occur in a completely new clear User?

Comment: Please answer the questions.

Comment: When you first open Xcode, you get a small window with 3 options:
- Get started with a playground - Create a new Xcode project - Clone an existing project, after clicking on any of these buttons Xcode immediately crashes

Comment: Okay, I've never ever used that window. I saw it once and dismissed it, telling Xcode I never wanted to see it again. So please do that. Click _none_ of those buttons. Instead, uncheck "Show this window when Xcode opens", and click the "x" that appears at the top left corner of the window. Now you'll never see that window again. When you want to create a new project, use Command-Shift-N. See whether that works. Thanks.

Comment: Did you rename your home/account? I had an issue with an installed XCode that crashed on opening storyboards because I renamed my account with/without and uppercase and all of the rest was working fine, except opening storyboard, path were case sensitive... Can you try on another account?

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the DerivedData directory in ~/Library/Developer/Xcode

or

Try Uninstalling Xcode and then Reinstalling it

Comment: I have tried uninstalling Xcode and reinstalling it, I have also tried uninstalling it and installing multiple different versions

Answer (score 0):

Looks like maybe something is wrong with your defaults.
Try running the below command to clear them out

```
defaults delete com.apple.dt.xcode
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely somewhere in code, there is an assignment of an `NSNumber` variable to an `NSString` variable.
Thus number object (instance 0xed1bd6c1b1e0a897) cannot respond to `hasPrefix:` [method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1410309-hasprefix?language=objc).

```swift
2020-04-05 14:51:44.095 Xcode[5709:184457] -[__NSCFNumber hasPrefix:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xed1bd6c1b1e0a897
```

Try to debug & figure out what actually this object is `0xed1bd6c1b1e0a897`, where it's being created and assigned to string object.
Once you find it - you can easily convert it to `NSString` by using `stringValue` [property](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnumber/1415802-stringvalue?language=objc).

I do presume you were able to build the project. If `Xcode` crashes even before build & run - I have no idea then.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting all these folders?

```
~/Library/Containers/com.apple.dt.BitbucketHostBuiltInExtension
~/Library/Containers/com.apple.dt.BitbucketServerHostBuiltInExtension
~/Library/Containers/com.apple.dt.GitHubEnterpriseHostBuiltInExtension
~/Library/Containers/com.apple.dt.GitHubHostBuiltInExtension
~/Library/Containers/com.apple.dt.GitLabHostBuiltInExtension
~/Library/Containers/com.apple.dt.GitLabSelfHostBuiltInExtension
~/Library/Containers/com.apple.dt.IDECacheDeleteAppExtension
~/Library/Containers/com.apple.dt.XCDocumenter.XCDocumenterExtension
~/Library/Containers/com.apple.dt.XcodeBuiltInExtensions

~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Instruments.plist
~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.SKAgent.plist
~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.ITunesSoftwareService.plist
~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.LSSharedFileList.plist
~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.Playground.plist
~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist
~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.xcodebuild.plist
```